# Remote debugging stopped working with CEF3

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I'm using CEF3 and had been using remote debugging without a problem. It's been days since I used it and I tried to use it today. Going to http://localhost:9000 should give me the list of frames, but instead it's just blank. Verified using curl that it was getting

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

from CEF. Anyone else run into this and have any ideas? It's definitely CEF that's on that port, returning (practically) nothing.

I'm using CEF 3.1750.1738.0 via Delphi Chromium Embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing cef.pak and devtools_resources.pak from my exe directory. It didn't click because my simple demos were ALSO outputting to that directory and thus "everything" was failing and not just one app. Went back to the DCEF distribution and tried it there and it was still set to output to the distrib bin dir and that worked fine. Figured it out, copied the files and it works fine.